# Is this a good server/subdomain set up

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, subdomain

At my work I am in charge of a few servers that are VPS's. What I generally do is give each server a name (at the moment I'm using the names of the 5 wizards from Tolkien's works).

Then in the zone file for our organization's domain, I set up a records for those servers. For example:

```
alatar.ourorganization.com 12.34.56.78
gandalf.ourorganization.com 98.76.54.32
```

And so on. Then each of these servers has its hostname set to alatar.ourorganisation.com or whatever.

Sometimes we want to have various things on those servers, like a survey or a reporting system or something like that, so to set that up I usually use a cname to set up the new subdomain, so for example:

```
reports.ourorganization.com gandalf.ourorganization.com
```

Is this a reasonable way of setting this kind of thing up? Are there any problems that could arise from doing things this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its fine. that's what we do also.

Just bear in mind if you want a server to be a mail server the mx record needs its real name, not a cname.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean with the mx record? Maybe an example?

Comment: @CameronBall Your MX record cannot point to a record which is itself a CNAME. At least, not if you want to receive mail.

Comment: So in general MX records should point to an A record or an ip address, correct?

Comment: MX records need to be populated with an A record, yes. I only mention it so it won't trip you up down the line when you make a CNAME of 'mail.ourorg.com' or such.